# How to prevent .setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled from re-creating the parent activity?

Tags: android

When I press the "back/up" button in the toolbar to go up one level, the parent activity is re-creating itself (re-loading data, etc.) when I'd just like to `finish` the current activity.

Right now my activity is automatically creating the `Toolbar` (support Toolbar), so I'm not sure how to select it to call `NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);` when it's clicked.

Is there a simple flag I can set it to tell it to just `finish` instead of re-creating the parent activity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use this trick and works, returns back to parent without re-creating the activity. The commented code recreates the parent. so i used finish()

```
@Override
public Intent getSupportParentActivityIntent() {
    /*String from = getIntent().getExtras().getString("from");
    Intent newIntent = null;
    if(from.equals("MAIN")){
        newIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    }else if(from.equals("FAV")){
        newIntent = new Intent(this, FavoriteActivity.class);
    }

    return newIntent;*/
    finish();
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in manifest delete `android:parentActivityName="YourParentActivity"` if you want to disable it completely

### update

override `onOptionItemSelected()` if you want to change its behavior

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
}
```

Comment: ah, sorry i meant the "up" button in the Toolbar, not the back button on your phone~